# Adding a custom Type Converter to Spring XD

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

Unfortunately, it seems like Spring XD doesn't ship with XML type converter (`application/xml`).

I implemented 2 `AbstractFromMessageConverter`s for converting POJO to XML and vice versa.

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#extending-xd) it says to look at streams.xml where I think they were really referring to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/module-type-conversion.xml) XML. I provided a list named `customMessageConverters` and my own Configuration which exposes these converters in an attempt to add them to Spring XD application context.

I wrote:

```
@Configuration
    @Slf4j
    public class XmlConverterConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public CompositeMessageConverter compositeMessageConverter(final  MessageConverter[] converters) {
                log.info("Registering XML converters");
                return new CompositeMessageConverter(Arrays.asList(converters));
            }
        }
```

And I added `@Component` annotation to my Converters.

And also this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Users can override this to add converters.-->
    <util:list id="customMessageConverters">
        <bean class="my.custom.mime.converter.PojoToXmlMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="my.custom.mime.converter.XmlToPojoMessageConverter"/>
    </util:list>

</beans>
```

and I tried adding this XML to `src/main/resources` and `src/main/resources/config` and then I put the compiled .jar to `$XD_HOME/lib` but it doesn't get registered properly.

I don't see the log from my Configuration and when I try to set outputType to `application/xml` I get an exception that it isn't supported:

```
org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.ModuleConfigurationException: Content type is not supported for outputType=application/xml
```

What step did I do wrong?

--EDIT--

I also uncommented these lines in `server.yml` and changed the basepackages to mine.

```
    ---
# User Extensions: Where XD scans the classpath to discover extended container configuration to add beans to the Plugins context.
# Each property may be a comma delimited string. 'basepackages' refers to package names used for
# annotated component (@Configuration or @Component stereotypes) scanning. 'locations' is a list of root resource directories containing XML or Groovy configuration.
# XD prepends classpath:* if no prefix included and appends **/*.* to each location
xd:
  extensions:
      basepackages: my.custom.mime.converter
      locations: META-INF/spring-xd/ext
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the file in a narrow folder, e.g. `/myCustomConverters` in the jar; then you have to tell XD how to find it by uncommenting the configuration in `serverys.yml` ...

```
# User Extensions: Where XD scans the classpath to discover extended container configuration to add beans to the Plugins context.
# Each property may be a comma delimited string. 'basepackages' refers to package names used for
# annotated component (@Configuration or @Component stereotypes) scanning. 'locations' is a list of root resource directories containing XML or Groovy configuration.
# XD prepends classpath:* if no prefix included and appends **/*.* to each location
xd:
  extensions:
#      basepackages: com.acme.xd.extensions
#      locations: META-INF/spring-xd/ext
      locations: myCustomConverters
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I uncommented the provided lines in the servers.yml and changed the basepackages to mine: my.custom.mime.converter.

Got it now, really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: You don't need the base packages, you need to tell XD how to find the xml with the `customMessageConverters` bean.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I removed my Configuration and removed @Component annotation from my converters and I put my XML in /resources/extension-config folder. I also configured my servers.yml by commenting out basepackages since you said I don't need them and I updated the locations to the extension-config folder. Still no luck, they aren't registered properly. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: It's a bug - the custom converters are loaded ok, but they are not consulted for their supported types during module deployment (only at runtime). I opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3749). I can confirm, though, that if you use `text/xml` instead of `application/xml`, it will work, because `text/*` passes the deploy-time check. But, of course, that won't help with your XML to POJO converter. You might need to use a transform module instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.